# Python 3 - WebSocket with Flask Thread Variable

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, flask, websocket

I'm using python3.4 and Flask.

I'm going to send message to the clients when the comments has been written.

Since I am using Flask, I should open server in the other thread.

In the server thread, `len(server.clients)` returns correct number of clients.

But when I call article_comments in the main thread, `len(server.clients)` returns 0, so no clients receive the message.

How can I solve this problem?

```
server = WebsocketServer(5001)

def server_thread():
    server.run_forever()

Thread(target=server_thread).start()

def article_comments():
    server.send_message_to_all("Hello World!")
```

Comment: Your question is unclear- where were comments written? In a Flask application (using a POST)? Are there other users listening using websocket connections? A websockets server can be opened on another thread, but then the main Flask application will have no access to the websockets internals. What library are you using to serve websockets? There are many details here regarding what you're trying to achieve and why that are missing. Please edit your question to clarify things to the community can help and also benefit from it.